# Why does the alkaline hydrolysis of benzamide yield ammonia?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Nucleophillic addition to the carbonyl group is governed by the rule that a less basic group is displaced by a more basic group since $\ce{NH2^-}$ is more basic than $\ce{OH-}$ the reaction should not proceed forward but it does why so?

Answer (score 1):

If the reaction were simply having the form

$\ce{RC(O)NH2 + OH^- <=> RC(O)OH + NH2^-}$

then your reasoning might well apply.  But, in the real world, the carboxylic acid $\ce{RC(O)OH}$ deprotonates (more than the amide $\ce{RC(O)NH2}$) and the proposed, strongly basic amide ion of course protonates to ammonia.  These proton transfer reactions push the displacement forward giving the true reaction

$\ce{RC(O)NH2 + OH^- -> RC(O)O- + NH3}$

Answer (score 1):

This reaction only proceeds under forcing conditions - concentrated OH- and high temperature. Every reaction is an equilibrium so a small concentration of NH2- will be formed. This is immediately protonated to NH3, and because of the elevated temperature this is boiled out of the reaction mixture. Thus the reaction proceeds (if only slowly) to completion as there is never an equilibrium concentration of NH2-.  Le Chatelier's Principle applies.

Comment: And as @oscar-lanzi says the RCO2H is also very quickly removed from the equilirium as RCO2-